# I am trying to add sound in native modules

Tags: react-native, react-native-native-module

i am current working on an application. What i want to implement is any time the NotificationModules screen is triggered i want to trigger a sound. here is my code and what i have tried so far. I am using native modules to trigger the sound. Hello guys, i am current working on an application. What i want to implement is any time the NotificationModules screen is triggered i want to trigger a sound. here is my code and what i have tried so far. I am using native modules to trigger the sound. Hello guys, i am current working on an application. What i want to implement is any time the NotificationModules screen is triggered i want to trigger a sound. here is my code and what i have tried so far. I am using native modules to trigger the sound.

```
package com.limestone.community;

import android.net.Uri;
import com.limestone.community.FullScreenActivity;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

public class NotificationModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    public static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    NotificationModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
        reactContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "NotificationModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void triggerFullScreenNotification(String title, String message, String channelId) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) reactContext
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(reactContext, FullScreenActivity.class);

        fullScreenIntent.putExtra("title", title);
        fullScreenIntent.putExtra("message", message);

        PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(reactContext, 0,
                fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(reactContext, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setContentTitle("Panic Alert")
                .setContentText("Immediate attention is required")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + reactContext.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.custom_sound))
                .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
};

        if (notification.foreground !== true) {
          if (notification.data.notificationType === 'Panic') {
            if (panicAlert === false) {
              dispatch(setTrue());
              saveBooleanData('notification', true);
              NativeModules.NotificationModule.triggerFullScreenNotification(
                notification.data.title,
                'A panic alert was raised in your estate',
                'limestone',
              );
            }
          }``
        }
```